# Implement web based desktop application with python

Tags: python, django, web-applications, desktop-application, node-webkit

I want to make a application that run as a web application or desktop application, I know how to implement for a web server using Django or Flask, i prefer Django, but is there any way to port it to a desktop application too? 
I found a nodewebkit that maybe give me the solution but, I don`t have any idea on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import wx
from wx.lib.iewin import IEHtmlWindow
a = wx.App(redirect=False)
f = wx.Frame(None,-1,"My Desktop Application")
browser = IEHtmlWindow(f)
browser.Navigate("http://google.com")
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

is a pretty good way for a remote web page to pretend to be a windows application ... assuming thats what you are asking for.. (this uses wxPython so of coarse you will need to install it)

Comment: this can be turn into executable with py2exe?

Comment: well I usually use pyinstaller

Answer (score 2):

Me personally prefer node-webkit(renamed to nwjs) for this kind of things. Its very easy and powerful, you should give it a try. here are some tutorials.

[this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296),
[this](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-node-webkit-apps/) and 
[this](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/creating-desktop-applications-with-node-webkit/).  here is the github page [nwjs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js).

but if your background is in python not nodejs then take a look at [cefpython](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/)